# Reattaching DOM element in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a situation which requires me to completely remove an element from the DOM and reattach it. To be more specific, a bug in the Airplay functionality leads to missing track information when changing the src of a video element:

1. Change the src attribute of the videoelement and start playing on Apple TV
2. Now switch the source to a different video
3. The track information (audio,text) are lost

I found a workaround which requires me to remove the video element from the DOM, create a new one and re-add it to the DOM. What would be the best way to do this with react? I tried setting the key attribute of my child component but this does not seem to do it. Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
class Container extends Component {
   render() {
    <Video key={this.videoElementKey} />
   }
} 

class Video extends Component {
  render() {
   return (
    <video id="vid" className="video-elem" playsInline />
  );

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
   }
}
```

The component gets remounted like I would expect. Does this imply that the videoelement is removed and readded again? Moreover, is the ref property of the component refreshed?

Comment: yes, `key` should help. by your example it's hard to realize what's wrong since `<Container>` has nothing common with `<Child>`. in you case, since you need to remount `<video>` after `src` is changed I believe you may use `key={this.props.urlToVideo} src={this.props.urlToVideo}`

Comment: just use that `<video>` as a component and render it by changing the props. Would be easier to have tracking in place.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong naming of Child. I fixed that, the Video component is now referenced in the Container component. However, it seems that remounting the Video component will not remove the HTML5 video element from the DOM. Because of the aforementioned bug in the Airplay implementation this is what I need. In plain JavaScript `document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('vid'));`

Comment: Hey @DanielSilhavy check out my answer below, it removes the component from the DOM via react https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598070/reattaching-dom-element-in-react-component/53599601#53599601

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of what you are trying to accomplish but, you may want to check **[unmountComponentAtNode](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode)** . It allows you to actually unmount your custom component and the references to it, not only the HTML elements. Then, you can add your component again.

You can do something like:

```
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById(yourNodeID));
```

Sorry it's not a very complete answer but it's hard without knowing more of your implementation. Anyway, maybe it points you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, still not sure if this is what I need. To be more precise. I need to to be able to really remove an element from the DOM. I would expect that React does this when my component is remounted, but apparently that is not the case. I am a litte bit surprised that this is so tricky. So in my example without React I just do this: `document.body.removeChild(video);` with video being `document.getElementById("video");`

Comment: Well, if what you want is to remove the HTML element node) from the DOM then you need to do something like what you posted in your comment above. React will not remove the element itself, since it will need some node to (re)mount the component... so, yeah, my previous answer is only useful if you remove the element/node and for some reason the component attached to it is not removed (in that case, it will stay in memory even if you can't see it).

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, to force the element unmounting, is to create two elements which extend your Video element, and switch between them when you update the `src`. With conditional rendering, on each change, one of the video components will be unmounted, and another will be mounted in it's place.

Following is the example using a set array of video `src`s:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const videos = [
  'https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a9KrqE1_460sv.mp4',
  'https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/a3Qq4PN_460sv.mp4',
  'https://img-9gag-fun.9cache.com/photo/aE2Yq9O_460sv.mp4'
];

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onNext = this.onNext.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      current: 0
    }
  }

  onNext = event => {
     this.setState((prevState) => ({
       // using modulo to stay within the length of videos array
       current: (prevState.current + 1) % videos.length 
  }));
};

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
          // switching between two video components if index is odd/even
        { this.state.current % 2 === 1
          ? <One current={this.state.current} />
          : <Two current={this.state.current} /> }
        <hr />
        <button onClick={this.onNext}>Next video</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Video extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <video key={'key-'+this.props.current} id="vid" className="video-elem" playsInline src={videos[this.props.current]}  />
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("componentWillUnmount");
  }
}

class One extends Video {}

class Two extends Video {}

export default App;
```

Running [example on repl.it](https://repl.it/@quarkon/ForceVideoElementUnmounting).